# Quantifiers in regex - example

Tags: regex

Could anyone please give a simple example of using quantifiers in regex. 
usage of greedy?,??, {min,max}

Comment: Go to the source. Download Perl from ActiveState. Install it, under docs dir, pull up the index.html (toc) and search for perlre.html. In there you will find %99 of _ALL_ constructs/examples and descriptions used in Regular Expressions engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to illustrate some of this would be a simple validation of a phone number with dashes between the digits and allowing for the area code to be optional:

```
/^([0-9]{3}\-)?[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$/
```

This is an excellent resource for learning regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html